# Avoid magic number when referencing an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, magic-numbers

I can't find a straightforward answer to this. How do I refer to parts of an element without using magic numbers?

In this case I am trying to place values of several cells from a row from an HTML table into variables:

```
const age = personRow.cells[1].innerText;
const sex = personRow.cells[2].innerText;
```

Comment: There is nothing magic about it when you really just mean "the second cell" and "the third cell".

Comment: If you do mean something more than what Bergi suggested, then what other information do you have?  Could you scan a header row for the table to see the indices of headers containing "Age" and "Sex"?  If so, perhaps you can exchange your magic numbers for magic strings...

Comment: @Bergi - Agree, though eslint doesn't allow it... Also just learning in general for indexed arrays.

Comment: @Trees4theForest Sounds like a rather dumb eslint rule. Disable or reconfigure it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had this issue before when using Google Sheets API to manipulate spreadsheets. You could just do:

```
const AGE_COL = 1;
const SEX_COL = 2;

const age = personRow.cells[AGE_COL].innerText;
const sex = personRow.cells[SEX_COL].innerText;
```

For simple code this works and is fairly self-documenting. However, you may need to handle several different types of table "structure". My solution to this is:

```
const FIELDS = {
    PERSON: {
        AGE: 1,
        SEX: 2
    }
}

const age = personRow.cells[FIELDS.PERSON.AGE].innerText;
const sex = personRow.cells[FIELDS.PERSON.SEX].innerText;
```

I find this to be even more readable and easier to extend.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this, is to get the index of the data field. Be advised, you could get an index out of bounds, if your fields noes not exist.

```
const FIELDS = [ 'age', 'sex' ]; // Defined in data header?

const age = personRow.cells[FIELDS.indexOf('age')].innerText;
const sex = personRow.cells[FIELDS.indexOf('sex')].innerText;
```

---

But, you should avoid the use of constants in the global scope. Instead, you should create an object to hold (scope) those values. This way, you can transform your data into an object accessible by keys.

```js
const FIELDS = [ 'age', 'sex' ];

var personRow = { 'cells' : [ 21, 'male' ] };

var data = {};
for (var i = 0; i < personRow.cells.length; i++) {
  var field = FIELDS[i];
  data[field] = personRow.cells[i];
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

---

You could design a function like so.

```js
var personRow = { 'cells' : [ 21, 'male' ] };
var data = dataArrayToObject(personRow.cells, [ 'age', 'sex' ]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));

/**
 * Returns an object from the data array. If no fields are specified,
 * the index of value will be used as the key.
 *
 * @param {object[]} data An array of values to assign to the given fields.
 * @param {string[]} fields The iterable, object keys.
 * @return Returns an array of key-value pairs specified by the indexed fields.
 */
function dataArrayToObject(data, fields) {
  fields = fields || [];
  return data.reduce((obj, val, i) => {
    obj[i < fields.length ? fields[i] : i] = val;
    return obj;
  }, {})
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Of course this doesn't set the `age` and `sex` variables requested... only properties of some object.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I understand, but that is just bad practice.

Comment: I don't really understand.  Of course, I'm with Bergi; there seems little wrong with the initial code.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I addressed the "initial" question, by grabbing the index of the field by requesting the position in an array. Better?

Comment: @MrPolywhirl: Sorry, I understood the code.  What I didn't understand is what you were saying is bad practice.

Comment: And in fact, that code (`const age = personRow.cells[FIELDS.indexOf('age')]`) is exactly what I was suggesting is simply substituting magic strings for magic numbers.

Answer (score 0):

you can [deconstruct](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the table row into variables without using indexes

```js
[...document.querySelector('#myTable').rows].forEach(row => {

  const [age, sex] = [...row.cells]

  console.log(age.innerText, sex.innerText)
});
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>Male</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>Female</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>Female</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

you can create empty arrays for `age` and `sex` and fill them in the loop ..